# Calling javascript method from objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

I am working on calling javascript function from objective C.
I have a function like this:

```
var ABC = {
    testingFunctionA : function() {
        alert("Testing ABC!");
        return "Hi";
    },

    testingFunctionB : function() {
        alert("Testing 123!");
        return "Hello";
    } };
```

I tried to call the function with this method, but its failed.

> NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
>   @"ABC.testingFunctionA()"];
>
> NSString *result = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];
>
> NSLog(@"returnValue = %@ ",result);

Anyone know the correct way to call the function?